# Finding $t$ with a power of $\frac{-1}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$40t^{\frac{-1}{2}} -10= 0$

$\frac{-1}{2} = 0.25$

I can't square root the $t^\frac{-1}{2}$ to remove the negative $1/2$ power . What can I do to find t?

Answer (score 2):

*HINT:*

Remember that $$a^{-b} = \frac{1}{a^b}$$

Answer (score 1):

$40t^{\frac{-1}{2}} - 10 = 0$

$40t^{\frac{-1}{2}} = 10$

$t^{\frac{-1}{2}} = \frac{1}{4}$

Raise both sides to the $-2$ power

$(t^{\frac{-1}{2}})^{-2} = (\frac{1}{4})^{-2}$

Multiplying exponents $\frac{-1}{2}$ and $-2$ leaves us with the exponent $1$ on the left side. So

$t^{1} = \frac{1^{-2}}{4^{-2}}$

Can you finish on your own?

Alternatively, you can multiply both sides of the equation by $t^{\frac{1}{2}}$ after moving the 10 over and dividing by 40, then you can square.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for non-zero real $a,b$ we have:

$$\left( t^{\frac{a}{b}} \right)^{\frac{b}{a}} = t$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
40t^{\frac{-1}{2}}-10&=0\\
\implies t^{\frac{-1}{2}}&=\dfrac{1}{4}\\
\implies \dfrac{1}{t^{\frac12}}&=\dfrac{1}{4}\\
\implies \dfrac{1}{\sqrt t}&=\dfrac{1}{4}\\
\implies\sqrt t&=4\\
\implies t&=16
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clever way to see this:

$$10 = 40 (16^{-1/2})$$

Substitute in and we get $$40t^{-1/2} - 40 (16^{-1/2}) = 0$$

$$40t^{-1/2} = 40(16^{-1/2})$$

From here we see that $t$ must equal $16$.